# Should the wiki of the EOL tag be edited to notify users that their questions will be closed?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-block-request, tag-wiki

Should  we add a notice to the tags wiki of those who have reached eol in bold, saying that if you're asking about this distro your question is likely to be closed because we don't answer such questions, something like that. So when the user is tagging his question, he'd notice that we no longer answer these questions.

This is one way to reduce the number of closed/unanswered questions discussed elsewhere on meta.

**EDIT**

I have edited the tag [11.10](https://askubuntu.com/tags/11.10/info) like so:

`Questions about this version are likely to be closed because it has reached its end of life.`

I left the wiki untouched, because we only want the users to see a brief warning when they pick the tag. If you agree with my edit please accept it and I will edit all the EOL tags for you, if you want, you don't have to worry about it. There's no harm in giving it a try.

Comment: Okay, part of the problem with this is that new users don't read the tag wiki - they read the excerpt that comes up when asking a question or hovering over a tag, and that cannot be formatted.

Comment: Yes, please do. @FEichinger The excerpt is for defining what questions you should use the tag for..

Comment: I'm in the band that version tags are utterly ridiculous and creating a new tag each 6 months for each new release when the issue has little to nothing to do with the version of Ubuntu they are using...

Comment: @Seth I'm just saying, chances are the people we'd be targeting with this wouldn't actually receive it.

Comment: @Braiam the first time, might be a lot of work, but next time, you just have to edit 1 tag every 6 month, coz only one release is released every 6 month, 13.10 will be eol, and thats it

Comment: @FEichinger maybe they do, some of them do, it wont solve the problem 100% but it will help, i'm not saying this is the solution that will do miracles, we all were newbies at some point

Comment: @FEichinger please read my edit

Comment: @Seth please read my edit

Comment: @Braiam please read my edit

Comment: @Fischer After your edit, the excerpt no longer tells the user what the tag is about. The existing excerpt also - [as Braiam noted in his reject reason](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/223695) - already included the information that this version is EOL. Perhaps that should be more prominent, and more directly tell the user *this question is off-topic*, though. :)

Comment: @FEichinger I see, do you have a better sentence then?

Comment: @Fischer After a quick discussion in chat, we've edited [this schema](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/223707) in for all EOL releases 10.10 through 13.04.

Comment: @FEichinger is it possible to see how much those tags are being used, just to know see if the number of EOL questions decreases or not.

Comment: @Fischer One could make a [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) query and group by week, for a history, but there's also the [tag overview](http://askubuntu.com/tags), which contains statistics on recently asked questions in those tags.